# GIS Blog Topics

Tags: discussion, blog

I was trying to figure out how to suggest - or offer - topics for the blog. I read a few Meta GIS.SE threads about the blog, but I did not find any of them where it was easy to vote topics up and down. Perhaps, this could serve as a container of potential topics? Let me start with a few answers and see if there is any interest on a blog topic.

Comment: If you want to write a blog post your more than welcome to do so. Can add you as an author if you want to contribute. This is also open to any other GIS SE users that wants to help add content to the blog. Just ask with comments here. WE NEED MORE POSTS - Stack Exchange employees are wanting 2 or 3 posts a month if possible.

Comment: @Mapperz I wanted to write an opinion about the biggest flaw in the GeoDatabase and the biggest pro over any other system since those are things that are never brought up by either propietary or open source camps. Who is approving the content of the blog right now?

Comment: Sounds good, will send you access via your email.

Answer (score 9):

The GeoDatabase Pros and Cons - an Ex Core GeoDatabase programmer's perspective.

Comment: You're obviously tha man to write that one.

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate what I'll call "non-technology" posts just as much as I do technology ones, in particular ones about cartography in general. Matt Wilkie's post, [It’s all about the data](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/its-about-the-data/) and Igor Brejc's post [Maperitive Tutorial: Generating OSM Map For Adobe Illustrator In Seven Easy Steps](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/maperitive-tutorial-generating-osm-map-for-adobe-illustrator-in-seven-easy-steps/) are good examples.

To boil it down, I like pretty pictures. Even if it is using tools or technology I don't use on a daily basis I'll tune in to check out the nice cartography in the post.

Note I'm not dissing technology posts. I'm sure alot of the community is interested in them, and Ragi and others have provided some really informative answers to topics I'm for the most part ignorant of. I'm sure alot of the community is interested in cartography as well though.

Comment: thanks man. I completely agree with you - cartography posts are definitely interesting

Answer (score 4):

I have a mini-tutorial on quickly prototyping ArcObjects applications using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) listed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32297/753), figured I might post here to see if anyone was interested in seeing it put on the GIS.SE blog -- especially considering it hasn't gotten a new post in months. Or do you think this is a little too niche for the general GIS.SE user base?

Comment: +1 Can't speak for the general user base, but I sure would like to see it.

Comment: +1 from me, as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is encouraging. I have posted a [question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716871/how-to-get-linqpad-to-dump-system-comobject-references) about an issue with this approach that I would like to figure out before submitting an article however. Maybe one of you gurus can help :)

Answer (score 3):

Deploying your GeoData on Mobile Devices